# How to retrieve nearest data from mysql using GPS coordinates?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, geospatial

I am using this SQL query to get data that is nearest to GPS coordinates.

```
SELECT geo_latitude, geo_longitude, geo_name, geo_country_code AS country, 
  (DEGREES(
    ACOS(
      SIN(RADIANS(47.470779)) * SIN(RADIANS(geo_latitude)) + 
      COS(RADIANS(47.470779)) * COS(RADIANS(geo_latitude)) * 
      COS(RADIANS(-87.890699 - geo_longitude))
    ) 
  ) * 60 * 1.1515)
  AS distance FROM `MyDatabase`.`allCountries` ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 20 ;
```

This query retrieves all the data irrespective of the distance. I would like it to display the data only within a radius of 10 miles. How can i achieve this?

Comment: what distance gives you ? the distance by miles ?

Answer (score 2):

There's two ways I've found.  One way is to do a direct SQL query with a whole lot of math in the 'where' section, much like you've tagged for your `AS distance` section of the SQL.  Essentially - conceptually - 'where distance < 10'

However, I've found that slows down my request ... so what I've done in addition is to pull out the square instead of the circle from the database.  Simply put:  figure out the 'ten miles west/north/east/south' coords, then put in `WHERE geo_latitude < X1 AND geo_latitude > x2 AND geo_longitude < x3 AND geo_longitude > x4` to put a hard limit on what I get back.  Then, if you really need to be that precise, cut off the corners by only displaying `if( result.distance < 10 ){`

Or to put it another way:

```
x1 = Coords + 10 miles north  
x2 = Coords + 10 miles south  
x3 = Coords + 10 miles east  
x4 = Coords + 10 miles west
```

by whatever means you're using to indicate '10 miles north', and then use that to pull out a 'square' of 10-miles north, south, west, and east from the center point.  As long as your `geo_latitude` and `geo_longitude` columns are indexed, this should be a fast database call.

Comment: i could understand the first idea !!! but wat do u mean by that x1,x2,x3,x4 in that second ? : wolfman joe

Comment: I've modified the answer.  I hope that helps clarify things?

Comment: And how do you compute x1 = Coords + 10 miles north

Comment: @qub1n The original post has the equation one can use to calculate distance based on lat / lon.

Comment: @WolfmanJoe: The original equation compares two/several gps points without any knowledge, how many miles is the resulted number. I just ask, how to implement miles/km to that equation.

Comment: You're feeding in lat/lon and getting out an m on the other side of the equation.  Well, the lat or lon remains constant, so that variable becomes a constant. Then you rebalance the equation so that it's based on m and finds the other lat/lon variable - and for how to do that I reference you to high school math classes.